# Importing data with formula from another google sheet and deleting original data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following script to import data from another Google Sheet but it doesn´t bring in the formula I need with it.

I have tried `ImportRange` but that seems to just sync the two sheets and I need to delete the data in the original sheet (Sheet 1) but that also deletes it in the sheet I bought in to (Master Sheet).

Is there another way to accomplish this?

```
function Copy() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Sheet 1 ID');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('results');
  var range = ss.getRange('2:688');
  var data = range.getValues();
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Master Sheet ID');
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('results');
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(
    data
  );
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Sheet 1 ID').getSheetByName('Roger');
  ss.getRange('2:688').clearContent();
}
```

Comment: could you share your spreadsheet I'll be glad to help. Now looks like you need to use `getFormulas` for what you are trying to achieve

Comment: If you want to transfer formulas, use `.getFormulas` instead of `.getValues`. if you need both, then use both, and replace the static values with the formulas for each cell by iterating the formula array. If you know ahead of time which ranges have formulas and which have static values, then use the appropriate call for the appropriate range. Consider also the `.copyTo` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue:

- Formulas are not retrieved with `getValues()`

#### Possible Solutions:

- Use `range#getFormulas` and `range#getValues` and mix those two arrays to create a array of formulas and  values to `setValues()` later.
- Use Advanced Google Services to access Sheets API to directly get the mix.

#### Sample Script Snippets:

```
  var data = range.getValues();
  data = range.getFormulas().map(function(e, i) {//i=index of row(e)
    return e.map(function(f, j) {//j = index of column(f)
      return f === "" ? data[i][j] : f;
    });
  });
```

or

```
  var req = {
    ranges: 'results!2:688',
    valueRenderOption: 'FORMULA', //get formulas with values
  };
  var r = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet('Sheet 1 ID', req);
  data = r.valueRanges[0].values;
```

#### References:

- [getFormulas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormulas())
- [EnablingAdvancedServices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)
- [batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)

Comment: I thought the sample script snippet 1 was the fix, it bought in the formula be was referencing Row 2 but that was not the row it was imported to so it didn´t solve my prob, Thanks

Comment: @Johnny So, That's why it's called a sample. It wasn't intended to solve your problem. It was intended to provide a general idea to solve your posted question. You're expected to do the rest of the work by trying again and again for a few days.