# How to make a data array with values and formulas

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to alter some code from a tutorial on how to remove duplicate rows from my sheet. The code works great for straight values, but some of my rows have cells with hyperlink formulas that I don't want to lose.

I think I need to make the spreadsheet data as an array, rather than just using getValues. It's been a long time since I've had to make an array, so I'm struggling with the best way to do this. I'll need for loops to populate the array and if statements to either get values or formulas depending on the row.

Here's the remove duplicates code that removes rows if the cell in column A and B match another row:

```
/**
 * Removes duplicate rows from the current sheet.
 */
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];

  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for (var j in newData) {
      if(row[0] == newData[j][0] && row[1] == newData[j][1]){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

So instead of just using one line to set the data variable, I need to build the array with values and formulas where appropriate. Otherwise, I lose my hyperlinks. How do I do this?

Edit: This question was solved by using an answer to another question. The questions' contexts are not the same, and the other question did not show up in any of my research, so I believe my question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing data with formula from another google sheet and deleting original data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701864/importing-data-with-formula-from-another-google-sheet-and-deleting-original-data)

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for sharing that! It didn't come up in any of my searches, but it definitely works!

Comment: If it answers your question, You can mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @TheMaster That question is quite a bit different from mine, and since it didn't show up for me in my many searches over some time, I don't want my question to be lost or disregarded. Even my very generic searches didn't yield that potential solution (i.e. without the context of removing duplicates, just searching for how to keep formulas and values). I want to preserve the context of my question and its uniqueness, so others who make that first specific search can get to an answer quicker. I disagree that it's a duplicate, but I thank you again for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by TheMaster, I was able to solve this. [Here's the original "Remove Duplicates" tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates), and [here's the question TheMaster directed me to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701864/importing-data-with-formula-from-another-google-sheet-and-deleting-original-data) to find the solution.

My final code:

```
/**
 * Removes duplicate rows from the current sheet.
 */
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var newData = [];

  var data = range.getValues();
  data = range.getFormulas().map(function(e, i) {//i=index of row(e)
    return e.map(function(f, j) {//j = index of column(f)
      return f === "" ? data[i][j] : f;
    });
  });

  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for (var j in newData) {
      if(row[0] == newData[j][0] && row[1] == newData[j][1]){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Comment: Also, there's a new inbuilt "Remove Duplicates" feature: Data>Remove duplicates. You might wanna try that.

Comment: @TheMaster The built in function doesn't exist on Google sheets, just excel.

Comment: Don't know if excel has it, but Google sheets introduced it recently for all versions: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-rfa43G2hKMM/XNLh5IKw0wI/AAAAAAAAH7w/4LEbkCaIP8MCP21TS6eqYIS1M0q3F_NEwCLcBGAs/s1600/1.gif

Comment: @TheMaster Weird! I don't have that option, and I'm missing a few of the other options like "trim whitespace" or "split text to columns." That's why I had to make a button in the first place. It also seems that this addition hasn't made its way around since it doesn't show up as a result of a google search. Edit: I looked for the source of your gif, and they started the gradual rollout of those features on May 8 and the rapid rollout actual didn't start until today.