# Googles Apps Script exact match

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using this script but it's replacing every instance of a T, A, etc. How do I get it to only replace an exact match? Only if it's the letter T and nothing else.

```
function runReplaceInSheet(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Underlevel");
  //  get the current data range values as an array
  //  Fewer calls to access the sheet -> lower overhead 
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  

  // Replace
  replaceInSheet(values, "/^T$/", '=image("https://i.imgur.com/Dxl893F.png")');
  replaceInSheet(values, 'A', '=image("https://i.imgur.com/omc7F9l.png")');
  replaceInSheet(values, 'R', '=image("https://i.imgur.com/12ZmSp3.png")');
  replaceInSheet(values, 'M', '=image("https://i.imgur.com/kh7RqBD.png")');
  replaceInSheet(values, 'H', '=image("https://i.imgur.com/u0O7fsS.png")');
  replaceInSheet(values, 'F', '=image("https://i.imgur.com/Hbs3TuP.png")');

  // Write all updated values to the sheet, at once
  sheet.getDataRange().setValues(values);
}

function replaceInSheet(values, to_replace, replace_with) {
  //loop over the rows in the array
  for(var row in values){
    //use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
    var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value) {
      return original_value.toString().replace(to_replace,replace_with);
    });

    //replace the original row values with the replaced values
    values[row] = replaced_values;
  }
}
```

Thank you :D

Comment: You used every other tag except Google-apps-script tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

- **String type instead of Regex object:** You're providing a String as first argument to `String#replace()` and expecting a regex type execution. `"/^T$/"` will be interpreted as a string literal  that starts with `/`, contains `^`,`T`, and `$`   and ends with `/`.

#### Solution:

- **Unquoted Regex:** Regex literal shouldn't be quoted with`"`.

#### Snippet#1:

```
/^T$/    //or new RegExp('^T$')
```

---

#### Snippet#2:

You can also just use `.replace()`  with a replacer function directly.

```
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var replaceObj = {
  //to_replace: imgur id
  T: 'Dxl893F',
  A: 'omc7F9l',
};
var regex = new RegExp('^(' + Object.keys(replaceObj).join('|') + ')$', 'g');// /^(T|A)$/
function replacer(match) {
  return '=image("https://i.imgur.com/' + replaceObj[match] + '.png")';
}
range.setValues(
  range.getValues().map(function(row) {
    return row.map(function(original_value) {
      return original_value.toString().replace(regex, replacer);
    });
  })
);
```

#### References:

- [String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)
- [Regexp object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)
- [createTextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createTextFinder(String))

Comment: Thank you :D

Both solutions work, but the problem I'm running into now is that when more than one string is entered it deletes the previous. So I type in a T and an R, for instance, it'll find and replace the T then delete it and replace the R.

Is this a Google Sheets thing or the code?

Comment: @Ryan `T` and `R` in a single cell? Like `TR` and it  outputs `R`?

Comment: No, sorry, different cells. It will replace the T, delete it, and then replace the different cell with the R in it. I've been toying with it, putting random T's, A's, R's all over the sheet and in groups. One at a time as well as inputting several. All previously replaced ones disappear and reappear as new strings are replaced. But then they won't reappear. Even waiting between doing a new cell, it'll still delete the previous ones. Hopefully this is making some sense! @TheMaster

Comment: I suppose I should note, the intent was to use this script more than once on the same sheet. Not sure if that changes anything or not. Probably worth mentioning, though, some of the scripts I saw for Find and Replace were meant to be used once it seemed like. @TheMaster

Comment: Previously replaced formulas `=image()` are deleted because  when you getValue(), the value is empty in a cell with image formula. Your value array should be a mix of formulas and values See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701864) on how to do that. If you have issues, ask a new question with enough details.