# Google Sheets Find and Replace script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I've been toying around with these two versions of a Find and Replace script. The issue I'm running into is that any consecutive uses of the script delete the previous uses. [As seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKSAR.jpg). I was referred to [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701864) but I either implemented them wrong or they weren't the fix needed.

I'd like to keep using the script instead of a one-time Find and Replace, if that's possible?

Definitely not the best at all this, sorry if I'm getting something easy wrong here! Thank you :)

```js
function runReplaceInSheet(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Underlevel");
  //  get the current data range values as an array
  //  Fewer calls to access the sheet -> lower overhead 
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  

  // Replace Staff Names
  replaceInSheet(values, /^T$/, '=image("https://i.imgur.com/Dxl893F.png")');
  replaceInSheet(values, /^A$/, '=image("https://i.imgur.com/omc7F9l.png")');
  replaceInSheet(values, /^R$/, '=image("https://i.imgur.com/12ZmSp3.png")');
  replaceInSheet(values, /^M$/, '=image("https://i.imgur.com/kh7RqBD.png")');
  replaceInSheet(values, /^H$/, '=image("https://i.imgur.com/u0O7fsS.png")');
  replaceInSheet(values, /^F$/, '=image("https://i.imgur.com/Hbs3TuP.png")');
  replaceInSheet(values, /^t$/, '=image("https://i.imgur.com/Dxl893F.png")');
  replaceInSheet(values, /^a$/, '=image("https://i.imgur.com/omc7F9l.png")');
  replaceInSheet(values, /^r$/, '=image("https://i.imgur.com/12ZmSp3.png")');
  replaceInSheet(values, /^m$/, '=image("https://i.imgur.com/kh7RqBD.png")');
  replaceInSheet(values, /^h$/, '=image("https://i.imgur.com/u0O7fsS.png")');
  replaceInSheet(values, /^f$/, '=image("https://i.imgur.com/Hbs3TuP.png")');

  // Write all updated values to the sheet, at once
  sheet.getDataRange().setValues(values);
}

function replaceInSheet(values, to_replace, replace_with) {
  //loop over the rows in the array
  for(var row in values){
    //use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
    var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value) {
      return original_value.toString().replace(to_replace,replace_with);
    });

    //replace the original row values with the replaced values
    values[row] = replaced_values;
  }
}
```

```js
function runReplaceInSheet(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Underlevel");
  //  get the current data range values as an array
  //  Fewer calls to access the sheet -> lower overhead 
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  

var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var replaceObj = {
  //to_replace: imgur id
  T: 'Dxl893F',
  A: 'omc7F9l',
  R: '12ZmSp3',
  M: 'kh7RqBD',
  H: 'u0O7fsS',
  F: 'Hbs3TuP',
};
var regex = new RegExp('^(' + Object.keys(replaceObj).join('|') + ')$', 'g');// /^(T|A)$/
function replacer(match) {
  return '=image("https://i.imgur.com/' + replaceObj[match] + '.png")';
}
range.setValues(
  range.getValues().map(function(row) {
    return row.map(function(original_value) {
      return original_value.toString().replace(regex, replacer);
    });
  })
);

var data = range.getValues();
  data = range.getFormulas().map(function(e, i) {//i=index of row(e)
    return e.map(function(f, j) {//j = index of column(f)
      return f === "" ? data[i][j] : f;
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to new value is replaced by keeping the existing values (images) when the script is run.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, I used below script in your question. Please modify as follows.

#### Modification points:

- In this modification, at first, both values and formulas are retrieved. And when for the cells which have the formulas, the same formulas are put. When for the cells which have the values, the replacement script is run and put the replaced formulas.
- By above flow, in this modification, `setFormulas()` instead of `setValues()` is used.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
range.setValues(
  range.getValues().map(function(row) {
    return row.map(function(original_value) {
      return original_value.toString().replace(regex, replacer);
    });
  })
);

var data = range.getValues();
data = range.getFormulas().map(function(e, i) {//i=index of row(e)
  return e.map(function(f, j) {//j = index of column(f)
    return f === "" ? data[i][j] : f;
  });
});
```

To:

```
// This part is not used in this modification.
// range.setValues(
//   range.getValues().map(function(row) {
//     return row.map(function(original_value) {
//       return original_value.toString().replace(regex, replacer);
//     });
//   })
// );

var data = range.getValues();
range.setFormulas(
  range.getFormulas().map(function(e, i) {//i=index of row(e)
    return e.map(function(f, j) {//j = index of column(f)
      return f === "" ? data[i][j].toString().replace(regex, replacer) : f;
    });
  })
);
```

#### References:

- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [setFormulas(formulas)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormulas(String))

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! It's keeping the existing images! However, it's trying to replace everything that has those letters in it. Instead of a standalone T, A, etc. [Picture here.](https://i.imgur.com/QKLf4nM.png) The text inside the cells is either =#ERROR! or =#NAME?

Comment: @Ryan King For example, I think to use the required data range using ``getRange()`` instead of ``getDataRange()``. But unfortunately, I think that it is difficult to decide whether this can resolve your new issue, because the information is not enough.