# Set formula to several cells script - there must be a more efficient way

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I'd like to apply the following to A2, A14, A26 and A28, and another formula to B2, B14, B26 and B28.  Right now I'm just doing the following, 4 times.  It works, but it ain't pretty.  How can I do this more efficiently?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets[7].setName('.NCF');
  
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[5];
  var cell1a = sheet.getRange("A2");
    cell1a.setFormula("=iferror(IF(QUERY('.NCF'!A2, \"where A contains '1ST'\")<>\"\", 1, ),\"\")");
  var cell1b = sheet.getRange("A14");
    cell1a.setFormula("=iferror(IF(QUERY('.NCF'!A14, \"where A contains '1ST'\")<>\"\", 1, ),\"\")");
  var cell1c = sheet.getRange("A26");
    cell1c.setFormula("=iferror(IF(QUERY('.NCF'!A26, \"where A contains '1ST'\")<>\"\", 1, ),\"\")");
  var cell1d = sheet.getRange("A38");
    cell1d.setFormula("=iferror(IF(QUERY('.NCF'!A38, \"where A contains '1ST'\")<>\"\", 1, ),\"\")");
    
  var cell2a = sheet.getRange("B2");
    cell2a.setFormula("=iferror(if(A2=1,query('.NCF'!A:A,\"Select A where A contains '( G54.1P'\"),\"\"),\"\")");
  var cell2b = sheet.getRange("B14");
    cell2a.setFormula("=iferror(if(A14=2,query('.NCF'!A:A,\"Select A where A contains '( G54.1P'\"),\"\"),\"\")");
  var cell2c = sheet.getRange("B26");
    cell2a.setFormula("=iferror(if(A26=3,query('.NCF'!A:A,\"Select A where A contains '( G54.1P'\"),\"\"),\"\")");
  var cell2d = sheet.getRange("B38");
    cell2a.setFormula("=iferror(if(A38=4,query('.NCF'!A:A,\"Select A where A contains '( G54.1P'\"),\"\"),\"\")");
}
```

Comment: Show the code for  two of those 4 times. You've shown only one. It's not clear what variables change

Comment: The first formula gets placed in A2, A14, A26, A38.  The 2nd formula get placed in B2, B14, B26, B38.

Comment: Quote the formula that needs to be in A14

Comment: var cell1a = sheet.getRange("A14");
    cell1a.setFormula("=iferror(IF(QUERY('.NCF'!A14, \"where A contains '1ST'\")<>\"\", 1, ),\"\")");

Comment: What about B14?

Comment: I'm going to edit the original to show exactly what I have now.

Answer (score 2):

- Use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) over row numbers and column letters.
- Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to create formulas to set.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = e.source;
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets[7].setName('.NCF');
  const sheet = sheets[5];

  let a1;
  ['A', 'B'].forEach(column =>
    [2, 14, 26, 38].forEach((row, i) =>
      sheet
        .getRange((a1 = column + row))
        .setFormula(
          column === 'A'
            ? `=IFERROR(IF(QUERY('.NCF'!${a1}, "WHERE A CONTAINS '1ST'")<>"",1,))`
            : `=IFERROR(IF(A${row}=${i +
                1},QUERY('.NCF'!A:A,"SELECT A WHERE A CONTAINS '( G54.1P'"),))`
        )
    )
  );
}
```

Also see [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

Here is my solution which is based on the same logic as TheMaster's answer.

```
  function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets[7].setName('.NCF');
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[5];
  const cells1 = ['A2','A14','A26','A38'];
  const cells2 = ['B2','B14','B26','B38'];
  cells1.forEach(c=>          
     sheet.getRange(c).setFormula(`iferror(IF(QUERY('.NCF'!${c}, \"where A contains '1ST'\")<>\"\", 1, ),\"\")`)
  )                                                
  cells2.forEach((c,i)=>          
     sheet.getRange(c).setFormula(`iferror(if(${cells1[i]}=${i+1},query('.NCF'!A:A,\"Select A where A contains '( G54.1P'\"),\"\"),\"\")`)
  )   
}
```

### Explanation:

Clearly, there are two sequences of cells and two formulas that you want to use. That is the reason that I use  `cells1` and `cells2` to denote the set of cells you want to apply formula 1 and 2 respectively. You want to call this expression: `sheet.getRange().setFormula` for every cell and this is why you can use the `forEach` function. Finally, I use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#:%7E:text=Template%20literals%20are%20string%20literals,editions%20of%20the%20ES2015%20specification.) to incorporate the elements of the `cells` tables into the string argument.

The main difference between my solution and the other solution is that my [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) statements are not linked between each other and I don't use if statements.

Comment: A lot of this is above my current ability, so this is a wonderful learning opportunity for me.  I'm already having fun playing around with it.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @ErikStenerud consider accepting an answer and also vote up if you like

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can apply the values in batch with [`setValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) for better performance. If you prepend the value with `=`, it is essentially the same as setting a formula, so the fact that you can only set values with the method does not matter.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  const sheets = ss.getSheets();

  sheets[7].setName('.NCF');

  const [, , , , , sheet] = ss.getSheets();

  const rng = sheet.getDataRange();
  const vals = rng.getValues();
  const formulas = rng.getFormulas();

  const mixed = formulas.map((r, ri) => r.map((c, ci) => c || vals[ri][ci]));

  const toFormula = [2, 14, 26, 38].map(r => r - 1);
  let formulaIdx = 1;

  const newVals = mixed.map((row, ri) => {
    if (!toFormula.includes(ri)) {
      return row;
    }
    row[0] = `=iferror(IF(QUERY('.NCF'!A${ri+1}, \"where A contains '1ST'\")<>\"\", 1, ),\"\")`;
    row[1] = `iferror(if(A${ri + 1}=${formulaIdx++},query('.NCF'!A:A,\"Select A where A contains '( G54.1P'\"),\"\"),\"\")`;
    return row;
  });

  rng.setValues(newVals);

  console.log(rng.getValues());
}
```

---

Runnable snippet with mocks:

```js
function Range(grid) {
  return {
    getFormulas() {
      return grid.map(row => row.map(({
        formula
      }) => formula));
    },
    setFormulas(formulas) {
      grid.forEach((r, ri) => r.forEach((c, ci) => {
        grid[ri][ci].formula = formulas[ri][ci];
      }));
      return this;
    },
    setValues(values) {
      grid.forEach((r, ri) => r.forEach((c, ci) => {
        grid[ri][ci].value = values[ri][ci];
      }));
      return this;
    },
    getValues() {
      return grid.map(row => row.map(({
        value
      }) => value));
    }
  };
}

function Sheet(spreadsheet) {

  /** @type {{ value }[][]} */
  const grid = [];

  let sheetName = "Sheet1";

  return {
    activate() {
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(this);
      return this;
    },
    insertColumns(columnIndex, numColumns) {
      grid.forEach(row => {
        const cols = new Array(numColumns).fill("").map(() => ({
          value: "",
          formula: ""
        }));
        row.splice(columnIndex, 0, ...cols);
      });
      return this;
    },
    insertRows(rowIndex, numRows) {
      const rows = new Array(numRows).fill("").map(() => [{
        value: "",
        formula: ""
      }]);
      grid.splice(rowIndex, 0, ...rows);
      return this;
    },
    getLastRow() {
      const {
        length
      } = grid;
      return length;
    },
    getLastColumn() {
      const lengths = grid.map(({
        length
      }) => length);
      return Math.max(...lengths);
    },
    getDataRange() {
      return Range(grid);
    },
    getSheetName() {
      return sheetName;
    },
    setName(name) {
      sheetName = name;
      return this;
    }
  };
}

function Spreadsheet() {

  const defaultSheet = Sheet(this);

  const sheets = [defaultSheet];

  let active = defaultSheet;

  return {
    getSheets() {
      return sheets;
    },
    getActiveSheet() {
      return active;
    },
    insertSheet(sheetIndex = 0) {
      const sheet = Sheet(this);
      sheets.splice(sheetIndex, 0, sheet);
      return sheet.activate();
    },
    setActiveSheet(sheet) {
      active = sheet;
      return sheet;
    }
  };
}

var SpreadsheetApp = {
  getActiveSpreadsheet() {
    return Spreadsheet();
  }
};

function onEdit(e) {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //prepare mock//
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    const sheet = ss.insertSheet();
    sheet.insertRows(0, 38);
    sheet.insertColumns(0, 2);

    const rng = sheet.getDataRange();
    const formulas = rng.getFormulas();
    formulas[5][2] = "=true";
    rng.setFormulas(formulas);
  }
  //end mock preparation//

  const sheets = ss.getSheets();

  sheets[7].setName('.NCF');

  const [, , , , , sheet] = ss.getSheets();

  const rng = sheet.getDataRange();
  const vals = rng.getValues();
  const formulas = rng.getFormulas();

  const mixed = formulas.map((r, ri) => r.map((c, ci) => c || vals[ri][ci]));

  const toFormula = [2, 14, 26, 38].map(r => r - 1);
  let formulaIdx = 1;

  const newVals = mixed.map((row, ri) => {
    if (!toFormula.includes(ri)) {
      return row;
    }
    row[0] = `=iferror(IF(QUERY('.NCF'!A${ri+1}, \"where A contains '1ST'\")<>\"\", 1, ),\"\")`;
    row[1] = `iferror(if(A${ri + 1}=${formulaIdx++},query('.NCF'!A:A,\"Select A where A contains '( G54.1P'\"),\"\"),\"\")`;
    return row;
  });

  rng.setValues(newVals);

  console.log(rng.getValues());
}

onEdit();
```

---

**Notes**

1. You have to [enable V8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration#incompatibilities) runtime to be able to use the snippet.
2. Be careful that if you have formulas in your data range you need to get them separately (with [`getFormulas`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulas)) and mix with the values (see how `mixed` variable is initialized).

Comment: Nice to see a lot of alternative solutions!

Comment: @TheMaster - true, as I mentioned that in chat, this modification is only a basis, I think I should mention it here ideed.

Comment: Related(to get mix of formula+values, if needed): https://stackoverflow.com/a/52705305

Comment: @TheMaster  I prefer relying on `||` operator behavior than on ternary operator, but that's purely preferential. Nice usage of the advanced service

Comment: I did too until a js expert showed me the difference. `0 || ''` will evaluate to  `''` instead of the correct value `0` in Google sheet. Same goes for `false`(checkboxes) [it is not a issue with setformulas though as it'll always be empty `""` or formula]. In any case, explicit is better than implicit

Comment: @TheMaster - I know this :) The trick is using formulas as basis, as they can either be empty or non-empty strings. Therefore, there should be no situation in which `"formula" || "value"` is interpreted incorrectly (unless docs lie about the public contract of the method)

Comment: @OlegValter Yes. Edited my previous comment before  your comment:) Edit: I think We had this same conversation before(long back- I remember saying "explicit is better than implicit"), where we just agreed to disagree (If I'm not mistaken)

Comment: @TheMaster got it - when I submitted, I saw only the original form of the comment. Anyways, in general, I agree that using `someVar === "" ? ifTrue : ifFalse` form is less error-prone, `||` operator is a "wield with caution" type of tool. Edit - you are correct, we had this conversation :)